# return result with non-existing model entity - EF .net Core 3

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-3.0

I would like to return a result by SP for columns which actually does not exist in current model entities.
Currently I am only able to return result which are one of the current model(s).

```
   [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> getAllSalaryRanks()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        using(db963Context context = new db963Context())
        {
            var ranks = context.IoVouchersSalaryRanks.FromSqlRaw("EXEC ioVouchers_sp_SalaryRanks").ToList();

            return Ok(ranks);
        }

    }
```

In the above example I will get an exception says : `The required column 'foo' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.`

Basically `IoVouchersSalaryRanks` is one of my models ,so the result's columns should be the exact as the model entity.
How can I add a custom model entity , so the SP will return a result matches to that custom model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stored procedure `ioVouchers_sp_SalaryRanks` must return a result that can be mapped to your entity `IoVouchersSalaryRank`

If it returns a custom results, you have to implement this way:

```
string query = "EXEC ioVouchers_sp_SalaryRanks";

var ranks = context.Set<CustomModel>().FromSqlRaw(query).ToList();
```

where CustomModel is a new entity where the properties can be mapped to the columns that are returned by your SP. So, if it returns only column foo with type string, it would look like this:

```
public class CustomModel
   {
       public string Foo{ get; set; }
   }
```

Add the CustomModel to the dbcontext in the method OnModelCreating

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomModel>().HasNoKey();
```

<s>I have a blog post that explains it, you can have a look here >>
https://mohamedsahbi.com/2019/05/22/raw-queries-with-entity-framework-core/</s>

Update: my blog was related to EF Core 2.1. So, I just updated the answer to work with EF Core3.1 You can find also a GitHub repos with a sample for EF Core 3.1 https://github.com/MohamedSahbi/RawQueryWithEFCore/tree/master/SampleWithEFCore/SampleWithEFCore3.1

Comment: 1. `Context.Query` is obsolete. we should use `Set` instead.
2. I'm getting an error  says : `Cannot create a DbSet for 'CustomModel' because this type is not included in the model for the context.`

Comment: ok, I need to check that. I did it with .net core 2.1. If you followed the blog you need to add this on dbcontext modelBuilder.Query<CustomModel>();

Comment: @YanivEliav you were right. I just updated my answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 3):

It means that column `foo` is not returned by your stored procedure. 
Try to:

- add your column `Foo` into your `SELECT` statement
- or use `[NotMapped]` for your `Foo` column. This attribute can be used for properties of an entity class for which we do not want to create corresponding columns in the database

Comment: I don't want `foo` to be in my `SELECT` statement. 
The model consists of other columns which 'foo' isn't one of them, but currently I'm using one of the models in my context(`IoVouchersSalaryRanks`) and I want the context to recognize a custom model  and not use `IoVouchersSalaryRanks `.

Comment: @YanivEliav ok, it looks like you've found a solution

Comment: unfortunately no.it was a mistake. it looked like it was the answer but wasn't after all

Comment: @YanivEliav you should create a POCO class that will be model for your columns from SELECT statement. `var ranks = context.FooModel.FromSqlRaw("EXEC ioVouchers_sp_SalaryRanks").ToList();`. EF Core does not allow execute `FromSqlRaw` without defining POCO class.